# Changing text of a h1 with jquery,,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hey guys im trying to change the text of a h1 with jquery. i want to change the text every time enter key is pressed  in a text area and the values are numeric values like on first enter the text should be 1 and on other it should be 2 and so on.. This is the code which im using...

**Jquery**

```
 <script>
        $('#_co').bind('keypress', function(e) {  //_co is the Id of Text area 
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            var id = 1;
            if(code == 13) {
                var text = $('#_line').text();
                     $('#_line').text(id);
                     id++;
            }

        });
        </script>
```

**Html**

```
<h1 id="_line">0</h4>
```

Comment: your html has `<h1>` closed by `</h4>`

Comment: try making a jsfiddle.  Also     ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any
    number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), 
    colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: the problem is finished :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move your declaration outside of that function,

```
var id = 1;

$('#_co').bind('keypress', function(e) {  //_co is the Id of Text area 
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

     if(code == 13) {
      var text = $('#_line').text();
      $('#_line').text(id);
      id++;
     }

});
```

And as Rohit said in the comment, You are having an invalid markup, Just close the `h1` tag properly,

```
<h1 id="_line">0</h1>
```

---

As per your new requirement you can use `.append()` in your current context.

```
var id = 1;

$('#_co').bind('keypress', function(e) {  //_co is the Id of Text area 
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

     if(code == 13) {
      var text = $('#_line').text();
      $('#_line').append('<br>'  + id);
      id++;
     }

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/rLSSF/)

Comment: can i set the text on a new line ??

Comment: @user3148503 Can you make a fiddle of that, so that we fix your problem easily.?

Comment: @user3148503 do you want to append the each number inside of that h1 right.?